# Issues with getting data from Google Spreadsheet with Zend Gdata - Empty result

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, gdata

I am trying to connect with Google spreadsheet using zend GData library as below code

```
// Google user account
$username = GOOGLE_USERNAME; // Your google account username
$password = GOOGLE_PASSWORD; // Your google account password

// Document key - get it from browser addres bar query key for your open spreadsheet

$key = GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_KEY;

// Init Zend Gdata service

$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($username, $password, $service);
$spreadSheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);


// Fetch recorded response data from Google Spreadsheet

try {
    // get spreadsheet entry
    $ssEntry = $spreadSheetService->getSpreadsheetEntry('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/' . $key);
   // get worksheets in this spreadsheet
   $wsFeed = $ssEntry->getWorksheets();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }
```

I am getting below error :

```
ERROR: DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input
```

Problem is Google removed ClientLogin facility from google API
Now I need to use zend GData library with OAuth or OAuth2

Please help me in this part, am in little hurry.

Or anybody knows any other PHP solution to achieve the solution. It will be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you had 2 years to fix it now Google shuts it down and your in a hurry now?   Check the https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: @DaImTo - 
Thank you for reply. I know its silly but it is the case for me.
Do you had any example for the same?